# Identification of tensor product as pullback

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be an affine variety, $f:X\rightarrow X$ a finite étale map of degree $n$ and $\mathcal{L}$ a locally constant sheaf on $X$. Is it then true that $f^*\mathcal{L}\cong \mathcal{L}^{\otimes n}$?

Comment: This question would be better with some more context, like what you tried and why you think this should be true (or not). See for instance the first bullet point at [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitely not. For instance, take $X = \mathrm{G}_{\mathrm{m}} \times \mathrm{G}_{\mathrm{m}}$. An \'etale map $f \colon X \to X$ is given by 
$$
f(t_1,t_2) = (t_1^{a_{11}}t_2^{a_{12}}, t_1^{a_{21}}t_2^{a_{22}}),
$$
where 
$$
a = \begin{pmatrix} a_{11} & a_{12} \\ a_{21} & a_{22} \end{pmatrix}
$$
is an integral matrix with $\det(a) \ne 0$. The degree of $t$ is $|\det(a)|$.

On the other hand, an irreducible locally constant sheaf on $X$ is given by a character $\mathrm{G}_{\mathrm{m}} \times \mathrm{G}_{\mathrm{m}} \to \mathrm{G}_{\mathrm{m}}$, i.e., by 
$$
(t_1,t_2) \mapsto t_1^{b_1}t_2^{b_2}.
$$

Finally, the action of $f^*$ on the locally constant sheaf corresponding to the character $b$ is just the action of the matrix $a$ on $b$, while the tensor power is just multiplication of $b$ by $n$. The results are usually not the same.

Comment: What a beautiful example! Thank you very much.

Comment: I guess I mostly would like to find a way to write tensors as pullbacks, so for the case of a torus if i want to write the n-th tensor power as a pullback, i could use the map $t\rightarrow t^n$?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.